# How can I use a macro to create a record in another table?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

Im currently inputting the same data into two different tables. I want to input record and add a number to the Number field on table 1 without having to input the same number on the Number field in table 2. How may I do this using a macro?

Comment: We will need some more information about your database. How are you adding the record? Via a form, or directly into the table? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Found how to do it..

Create record in: Table1

```
    Set Field
             Name: Number
             Value = Int([table2].[FieldName])
```

Comment: This is a `Data Macro`, not a regular Macro.  It is created while in Design View on the Access table.  One issue with Data Macros however is that named data macros cannot be called from the Client database, they can only be called from the same database where the table resides.  For your situation however, using the AfterUpdate on one table to create a record in the second would work.